# Does selenium search elements from bottom or top of the DOM

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Because when I used testcomplete, I remember someone saying the driver implementation in jscript somehow said it searches from bottom most element and then comes to the top...

So with respect to selenium, how does the traversal happens, does it traverse from the top of the DOM ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selenium implements a breadth-first search, meaning it starts from the root of the DOM and walks through all immediate children. Afterwards, it goes through the children of each children.

[image]

Therefore, if you search for `tr td` on the tree below, it will find the *Shady Grove* node.

[image]

In the Inspect Element view, it would be something as

```
.
+-- table
|   +-- rows
    |   +-- tr
        |   +-- td (Shaddy Grove)
        |   +-- td (Aeloian)
    |   +-- tr
```

Comment: Is Shady grove technically the bottom most as seen via HTML? Considering when we inspect same .. there is always left to right indentation of nodes right .. so like shady grove goes on top you mean?

Comment: It would be the top - the first option. I've added view similar to the Inspect Element - tell me if it is clearer.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would add the source of the information provided.

Comment: @AlexeyR. https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-Location-Steps